# How to make a particle simulation like this?

Tags: particles, physics, fluid-simulation

So here is the reference
https://www.instagram.com/p/CHijzp2gVt7/

I don't ask for like exact guideline how to make it, but if you can throw me a few steps or tutorials for something specific as this. Or give me a few tips. Anything really would help.

I try to look around on YouTube, Google, ask around here and get as much information I can find.
I am looking into this new tools MantaFlow and FlipFluids.

So on the video he has like Triangle, Spherical, Square shapes with particles inside.
It simulates like water but it has small spheres, maybe I don't have to get it exactly like that. But getting something a tidy bit close to that, would be great. I don't have to type it all down, the reference explains it quite well.

By the way I do have slight experience with particles and simulation, I'm not completely new with it.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try in 2D with a plane and a noise texture. You could add keyframes to change the texture over time and make it move like in your example. Then multiply it to another noise texture (with a MixRGB node) to create this noisy particle effect. Otherwise if you want to go with particles : create the scope with a simple shape and collision property, remove gravity from particles, and add a turbulence force in the scene. Then rotate both emitter and turbulence.